# What is TemplateResolver.setOrder user for in thymleaf?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf for my email templates and I was googling and was able to run the code successfully with the following config:-

```
@Configuration
public class TemplateEngineConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MailConfigProps mailConfigProps;

    @Bean
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
        return templateEngine;
    }

    private TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        TemplateResolver resolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix(mailConfigProps.getTemplatePath());
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setCacheable(true);
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Everything here is understandable to me except setOrder. I tried looking up for it in different places and the only info that I get is that " *Sets a new order for the template engine in the chain. The order should start with 1.*".

Below is what documentations says:

```
setOrder
public void setOrder(Integer order)
Sets a new order for the template engine in the chain. Order should start with 1.
Parameters:
order - the new order.
Can someone please share why `setOrder` is there and when should it be used in my application and what should be the appropriate values to be set in different scenarios.
```

What happens if I don't provide this value?

Comment: Please post the documentation as a text, I can't read it ;)

Comment: well you should have been clicking on the image but for now i have added in text

Comment: It is better to use text instead of image, first I don't want to open a different page just for an image (those on mobile will thank you for that). And of course, referencing of the page is better with text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application may use different types of Templates like `HTML, TXT or String` etc.Those may have multiple types of template resolvers. Those multiple template resolver can be registered with the `template engine`. All the view resolvers in the application executing in the ordered chain until one of them are able to resolve that view.So, `TemplateResolver#setOrder` basically decide the order of the chain. There is a `resolvablePatterns` property which is the one to determine whether a template resolver will consider a view name to be resolved by it or not. You can also set the `resolvablePatterns` by `setResolvablePatterns`

```
templateResolver.setResolvablePatterns(Collections.singleton("text/*"));
```