# Thymeleaf with mule not resolving the HTML path under the resource

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I have used references:
[What is TemplateResolver.setOrder user for in thymleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50055626/what-is-templateresolver-setorder-user-for-in-thymleaf)
https://memorynotfound.com/spring-mail-sending-email-thymeleaf-html-template-example/

I have project structure as :

prj/
module/
src/
main/
java/
services/
servicePgm1.java
resource/
servicePgm1.html

In servicePgm1.java I have coded as:

```
private SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("src/main/resources/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        resolver.setCacheable(false);
        return resolver;
    }

String getEndpoint() throws MuleException {
    final TemplateEngine tplEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable(SUB_TITLE_PLACEHOLDER, "title 1");
    engine.process("servicePgm1", context);
```

}

The engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver()) is returning InvocationTargetException from abstract class AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher implements ResourceMethodDispatcher

Comment: Maybe you should try `resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/");`

Comment: Does not seem to resolve with classpath:/

Comment: Also tried - this.class.getClassLoader().getResource("servicePgm1.html").getPath()